# Idiomatic way to cheaply remove an element from an arbitrary container?

Tags: c++, containers, std, idioms

All C++ standard library containers have an `insert()` method; yet they don't all have a `remove()` method which does not take any arguments, but performs the cheapest possible removal at arbitrary order. Now, of course this would act differently for different containers: In a vector we would remove from the back, in a singly-list list we'd remove from the front (unless we kept a pointer to the tail), and so forth according to implementation details.

So, is there a more idiomatic way to do this other than rolling my own template specialization for every container?

Comment: Not really. I mean, what would you remove from an unordered_set by default? And by "you" I mean if you had to write such a standard utility for the standard library.

Comment: In C++17, you have the `extract` methods for associative containers, but naturally you'd need to supply which element to remove.

Comment: you don't have "all in one" container. some containers are optimized for removal an arbitrary element (like deque), some are optimized for adding elements, etc. if we had a cheap way of doing XXX, we would have only one container.

Comment: The only use case I can see for removing a "random" element is removing all elements one by one, when the order of removal doesn't matter. But then it's usually easier to iterate over all elements (`for (auto const& element: container)` followed by removing all elements (`container.clear()`). That is already uniform for all containers.

Comment: You don't need a specialisation for every container template. Just every common trait of such templates. For example, maps, sets, vectors, lists can all just pop the back() element. Obviously a queue and stack will pop whichever element they dictate. 
In a sense, what you are talking about is decoupling the behaviour of say std::queue from its storage implementation (probably not a bad idea).

Answer (score 0):

Part of the design of the standard containers is that they ONLY provide operations as member functions if it is possible to provide one that is optimal (by chosen measures) for that container.

If a container provides a member function, that is because there is some way of implementing that function is a way that is optimal for that container.

If it is not possible to provide an optimal implementation of an operation (like `remove()`) then it is not provided.

Only `std::list` and (C++11 and later) `std::forward_list` are designed for efficient removal of elements, which is why they are the only containers with a `remove()` member function.

The other containers are not designed for efficient removal of arbitrary elements;

- `std::array` cannot be resized, so it makes no sense have have either an `insert()` OR a `remove()` member function.
- `std::deque` is only optimised for removal at the beginning or end.
- Removal of an element from `std::vector` is less efficient than other containers, except (possibly) from the end.

Implementing a `remove()` member function for these containers therefore goes against the design philosophy.

So if you want to be able to efficiently remove elements from a container, you need to pick the right container for the job.

Rolling your own wrapper for the standard containers, to emulate operations that some containers don't support is simply misleading - in the sense of encouraging a user of your wrapper classes to believe they don't need to be careful with their choice of container if they have particular requirements of performance or memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your question

*"So, is there a more idiomatic way to do this other than rolling my own template specialization for every container?*

There are lot of  ways to do remove

1. Sequence container and unordered container's erase() returns the next 
   iterator after the erased item.
2. Associative container's erase() returns nothing.

/*
 * **Remove from Vector or Deque**
 */

```
 vector<int> vec = {1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 12, 18, 16}; // To remove all '1'
  for (vector<int>::iterator itr = vec.begin(); itr != vec.end(); ++itr) {
     if ( *itr == 1 ) {
        vec.erase(itr);
     }
  }   // vec: { 4, 12, 18, 16}
  // Complexity: O(n*m)

  remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1);  // O(n) 
                                      // vec: {4, 12, 18, 16, ?, ?, ?, ?}




  vector<int>::iterator newEnd = remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1);   // O(n)
  vec.erase(newEnd, vec.end());  

  // Similarly for algorithm: remove_if() and unique()


  // vec still occupy 8 int space: vec.capacity() == 8
  vec.shrink_to_fit();   // C++ 11
  // Now vec.capacity() == 4 

  // For C++ 03:
  vector<int>(vec).swap(vec); // Release the vacant memory
```

/*
 * **Remove from List**
 */

```
  list<int> mylist = {1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 12, 18, 16};

  list<int>::iterator newEnd = remove(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), 1);  
  mylist.erase(newEnd, mylist.end());


  mylist.remove(1);  // faster
```

/*
 * **Remove from associative containers or unordered containers**
 */

```
  multiset<int> myset = {1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 12, 18, 16};

  multiset<int>::iterator newEnd = remove(myset.begin(), myset.end(), 1);  
  myset.erase(newEnd, myset.end()); // O(n)

  myset.erase(1); // O(log(n)) or O(1)
```